# How to translate 渗透渲染？

Tags: translation

The Chinese text has 渗透渲染 as a compound noun. This is a bit difficult to render in English. I split it up. Any suggestions on how to keep it as 1 word?

渲染： 画国画时用水墨或淡色涂抹画面以加强艺术效果

泰山位于山东省中部，
Taishan lies in the middle of Shandong Province,
自然景观雄伟高大，
(its) natural scenery is of imposing heights,
有着数千年精神文化的渗透渲染
permeated (渗透) by a backwash (渲染) of millenia of spiritual culture
和人文景观的烘托(offset)。
and offset (烘托) by man-made places of cultural interest.

Comment: some users question use of computer graphics term "rendered" (see answer (alternative suggestion: "permeated and embellished")  bkrs: 渲染 
**rendering (computing)**
to add washes of ink or color to a drawing (Chinese painting)
to exaggerate
to embellish

Comment: render = translate. You should know that! If you start writing your answers in the answer box and stop referring to yourself in the third person, I will give you a Christmas present! Frohe Weihnachten Ja!

Comment: comment #1 refers to (strange sounding) "rendered by millenia" in bottom answer

Answer (score 2):

I think 渗透 and 渲染 are juxtaposed here, so

> permeated (渗透) by a backwash (渲染) of millenia of spiritual culture

should be

> permeated and rendered by millenia of spiritual culture

Comment: Thanks but, what meaning do you see in 'rendered'? Here are some choices: Meaning "hand over, deliver" is recorded from late 14c.; "to return" (thanks, a verdict, etc.) is attested from late 15c.; meaning "represent, depict" is first attested 1590s. It should be permeated by 'something' '数千年精神文化的' is 'of millenia of spiritual culture', an adjective phrase, so what permeates it? Therefore I don't think the use of 'rendered' is correct here. It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Pedroski  It's a term used in computer graphics and is borrowed from ancient painting art(so is 渲染), so I think it would be a proper translation for 渲染. Maybe it's confusing to natives? Anyway this doesn't affect how the sentence is parsed :)

Comment: Haha, render is an old word. Computer graphics (maybe 30 years old) did not invent the word, they borrowed it: rendering: mid-15c., "action of restoring," verbal noun from render (v.). Meaning "a translation" is from 1640s; that of "extracting or melting of fat" is from 1792. Visual arts sense of "reproduction, representation" is from 1862. '1862' is not ancient! Not confusing, just not applicable here in my opinion. I was hoping for 1 word for '渗透渲染', I don't think that is possible. The expressive power of Chinese is amazing!